# Is "pending" a postpositive adjective?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

> She had a libel action against the magazine ***pending***.

"Pending" in this sentence seems weird, as it is unlikely to modify the noun "magazine" like other postpositive adjectives such as "the president ***elect***","information ***available***" .

Does "pending" modify the noun "action"?

Comment: Adding brackets (which is legitimate) to the prepositional phrase clearly shows that 'pending' doesn't modify 'the magazine: 'She had a libel action (against the magazine) pending.'

Comment: Agree. But why is " pending" placed at the end, instead of immediately following "action"?

Comment: *Pending* is a verb which post modifies the noun phrase *a libel action (against the magazine)*.  You’ll notice that *against the magazine* comes after the verb *pending* in your example. This is an example of **extraposition from noun phrase** movement. This is when a *heavy* phrase after the noun (i.e. a long one) becomes detached from it and occurs at the end of the clause.

Comment: Normally, it would be "a libel action pending against the magazine". Nothing heavy there, just a choice to put it at the end.

Comment: To do that, the speaker must analyze _a libel action pending_ as a noun phrase, which is not unusual, but it interrupts the potential NP _a libel action against the magazine_. Or maybe some speakers can parse them simultaneously, like the passive _sleep in_ in _This bed was slept in by someone famous_.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be a post-positive adjective as that would imply that there were a single constituent, noun phrase *a libel action against the magazine pending*. This is clearly not the case as it can't be used as a subject or object.

> *[A libel action against the magazine pending] was dropped.
>
> *He was referring to [a libel action against the magazine pending].

The clause is a transitive construction with an object oriented complement, where *pending* is an argument of the verb *had*.

> [ Subject] { predicate [ object ][ object oriented
> complement ] }
>
> [ She ] { had [ a libel action against the magazine ] [ pending ] }.
>
> [ She ] { had [ it ] [ pending ] }

Similar constructions can have preposition phrases, predicative adjective phrases, and non-finite clauses as the object-oriented complement.

> [ I ] { had [ them ] [ at the door ] }
>
> [ I ] { had [ them ] [ angry ] }
>
> [ I ] { had [ them ] [ chasing me ] }

It could be argued that it is any one of these. In any case what's relevant is, that since it does not form a constituent with the preceding noun phrase, it does not modify it, but is instead an argument of the verb *have*.

Answer (score 0):

[*Webster's New World College Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pending) certainly regards this usage as that of an adjective:

> **pending** [in American English]
>
> [adjective]
>
> 1. not decided, determined, or established
>
> - *a pending lawsuit*
> - *patent pending*

*Collins Cobuild Advanced Learner’s Dictionary* [same link] similarly classes the usage as that of an adjective, and includes the example here:

> **pending 1.**
>
> [adjective]
>
> If something such as a legal procedure is pending, it is waiting to be
> dealt with or settled. [formal]
>
> - *The cause of death was listed as pending.*
> - *In 1989, the court had 600 pending cases.*
> - *She had a libel action against the magazine pending.*

And *Collins English Dictionary* [again, same link] describes the usage as postpositive:

> **pending** [in British English] ...
>
> [adjective (postpositive)]
>
> 2. not yet decided, confirmed, or finished
>
> - *what are the matters pending?*

However, there is often difficulty in agreeing on the POS of such ing-forms. Choice of constituency testing is involved, and often there is no consensus. The verby nature is perhaps brought out if one compares with an even more archaic form *what are the matters that are pending?* which looks like it uses a present participle. Some would say that as there's no DO, this should be classed as an adjective usage, but they don't usually mention that intransitive verbs happily form present participles. And incidentally, consider the difference between

- *Can you see the man snoring?* (≅ '... the man who is snoring')
- *Can you hear the man snoring?* (does **not** default to '... the man who is snoring')

And as tchrist points out, a similar sentence such as

- *She had a libel action against the magazine taking up all her time*.

would be analysed as containing a verbal ing-form.

In spite of the references above, I'd agree that this is best not considered an adjective usage.

Comment: "Sorry, I can't talk now. I've got a taxi at the kerb running up its meter on me."   You wouldn't call *running* a "postpositive adjective", and I don't see this usage being any different from that one.

Answer (score -1):

"Pending" is an object complement that follows the direct object "action" and describes it.

It is a verbal acting as an adjective, but not a real adjective.

Here is what Wikipedia says about [object complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_complement):

> In grammar, an object complement is a predicative expression that follows a direct object of an attributive ditransitive verb or resultative verb and that complements the direct object of the sentence by describing it.[1][2][3] Object complements are constituents of the predicate. Noun phrases and adjective phrases most frequently function as object complements.

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question, which is specifically about the positioning of *pending* in this example? Note the OP's elaborating on the question in a comment: 'why is " pending" placed at the end, instead of immediately following "action"?'